# node/getstream: user creation fails: client.user(uid).create() => 500

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

Versions:

- node: v12.14.0
- getstream: 4.3.0

I am experimenting with user creation as described in the [documentation](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#users_create).
However, creating a user `client.user(userId).create({type: 'normal'})` always fails with `500`. Similar to the Github [issue 232](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/issues/232).

Error message: `{"detail":"","status_code":500,"code":-1,"exception":"InternalServerException","duration":"0.51ms"} with HTTP status code 500`

Anyone an idea what may be going wrong?

Fyi:

- I am able to create and fetch feed/activities. So, the client works.
- right now I simply experimenting with some scripts.
- the `userId` is a string, not very long (<30 chars), alphanumeric

**Update**:

Same error occurs after these attempts:

- Using latest version `4.4.0`
- Using REST-API/curl as [documented](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#user). Example command: `curl -i -X POST -d '{"id":"bob","data":{"extra":"fields","flag":false}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Stream-Auth-Type: jwt" -H "Authorization: JWT-TOKEN" "https://tokyo-api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/user/?api_key=API-KEY"`
  The command in the documentation is generated using key/token, but it also changes the URL endpoint to `tokyo-api.stream-io-api.com`. I also tested this with the domain `api.stream-io-api.com`, and the opposite, using `tokyo-api.stream-io-api.com` in the library (overwritten manually) without success.

Comment: I believe this was solved by a fix that went live at the end of the year. Could you try this again?

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli thanks for the suggestion. However, updating did not resolve the issue. Also, since the rest-api returns the same error, it seems to me that this is not related to the library used.

Comment: For the record, there was a feature difference between data centers (Tokyo vs USA) where this app was hosted. Now, they are equal so everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just "closing" this one. As @ferhat-elmas mentioned in the comment, this was at the time of asking the question not supported for region `tokyo`. I just tested this now from region `tokyo` and the creation of user (and reaction as well) works as documented.